# How to read a line in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

please help me to read multiple integers from a line using multiple scanf in C++. Is it possible, or should I use a different function?

I am a novice in programming, so a detailed answer is appreciated.

I tried and somehow discovered that:

```
scanf_s("%d ", &a);
scanf_s("%d ", &b);
```

if I input to this code
line1: 3 5
The code can read both of them.

Please help me resolve the following code.

```
vector<int> my_vec;
int size;
scanf("%d ", &size);
for(int k = 0; k<size; k++)
{ int elements;
    my_vec[k] = scanf("%d ", &elements);
}
```

I am trying to read a line where the first number is the size of the vector and the following integers are the elements of the vector.

For example, line: 4 7 9 3 6
it should store
vector my_vec = {7, 9, 3, 6};

When I tried this code on visual studio, it just terminated when run.

Comment: `my_vec` is empty so `my_vec[k]` has undefined behaviour, you need to use `push_back`

Comment: Read about what [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) returns. There's no need to use `scanf` though. `if(std::cin >> size) { std::vector<int> my_vec(size); for(int& element : my_vec) std::cin >> element; /* work with my_vec here */ }`